# Screen randomly locks with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04. Since the upgrade I have been having a problem with the screen going black and taking me back to the login screen. It seems to happen most often when I am using Firefox but it will happen occasionally when I am using other programs. Is there a way to fix this?